# Changing Title of Panaroma in Windows phone 8 application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-mobile

I am making Windows phone application, which is a panorama app. I wanted to change font color and style of title of app. I have used technique like to include "textblock" and then customizing font style of textblock. But it didn't worked.

Howto do it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you want to do:
[image]

You just need to change the style of the Panorama element.

Here is the code for the image above

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="phone:Panorama">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <phone:Panorama Title="my application">
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

If you don't know how to create styles, create a copy of the style of the current element and edit to your liking. I've written up a [blog post](http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/07/22/example-winrtmetro-app-how-to-edit-default-template-in-visual-studio-2012-and-blend/) for another SO user here how to do that :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You want to change the title template of the panorama:

```
<controls:panorama title="my application" titletemplate="{StaticResource SmallPanoramaTitle}">
```

Here's the template:

```
   <application.resources>
            <datatemplate x:key="SmallPanoramaTitle">
                <contentpresenter>
                    <textblock text="{Binding}" fontsize="50" margin="0,70,0,0" />
                </contentpresenter>
            </datatemplate>
    </application.resources>
```

This will let you completely change what your Title looks like.

Answer (score 3):

in VS2012, VB.NET I needed to set using proper case:

```
<phone:Panorama Title="my application" TitleTemplate="{StaticResource SmallPanoramaTitle}">
```

and in App.xaml file

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SmallPanoramaTitle">
        <ContentPresenter>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="50" Margin="0,70,0,0" />
        </ContentPresenter>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```